# Apache Storm - KafkaSpout not consuming messaes from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-storm

I am trying to integrate Kafka to Storm Toplogy using below code but unfortunately KafkaSpout is not consuming messages from Kafka-topic. At Storm UI-Core, Emitted count remains 0 forever.

```
String bootStrapServer = "10.20.10.238:9092";
String topic = "test.topic";

KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder spoutConfigBuilder = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootStrapServer,topic);
spoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG,100*1024*1024);
spoutConfigBuilder.setProp(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG,100*1024*1024);
spoutConfigBuilder.setProcessingGuarantee(KafkaSpoutConfig.ProcessingGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
Boolean readFromStart = true;
if(readFromStart) {
spoutConfigBuilder.setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.EARLIEST);
} 
else {
spoutConfigBuilder.setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.LATEST);
}

KafkaSpout spout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfigBuilder.build());
builder.setSpout("kafkaSpout", spout, 1);
// And a Bolt to see messages
builder.setBolt("fcBolt", new FcBolt(), 1).setNumTasks(1).shuffleGrouping("kafkaSpout");
```

But when I tried to see the produced messages from CLI , I am able to see all messages on topic with below command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test.topic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server 10.20.10.238:9092


Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx128000m
test
test
test1
....
```

**Versions:**

```
Storm : 2.2.0
Kafka : 2.13_2.6.0
```

At old versions,it works fine! Something I had missed to read at newer version.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know with what you have, so consider showing the rest of your code too.
But from what you do have, it does not appear like you are actually producing any events.

If you are trying to consume kafka events in your spout for further processing then make sure you are actually subscribed to a topic that is having events created on it, and then you can not see the event output through the console consumer since you are consuming them in Storm, not producing them.

If you are trying to produce kafka events to the test topic through Storm and then trying to consume them through the console consumer then make sure you are actually producing events in storm.

Hope that puts you on the right path, I would suggest going over the base-concepts of Kafka here: [Kafka Introduction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#gettingStarted)

Comment: While producing event I had tried to put the events with zookeeper IP and not trough broker server IP. With latest versions of Kafka(2.6.0) all information are stored at broker/bootstrap-server - so not required to communicate zookeeper directly for such producer-subscriber events.